# Why Demo data work for my complete.R function, but data from quiz not?

Tags: r

According to the following requirement, I have written a function complete.R

[Requirement in Quiz 2 of R Programming (Coursera)](https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming/supplement/amLgW/programming-assignment-1-instructions-air-pollution): Write a function that reads a directory full of files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. The function should return a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases.

Here is my code of complete.R:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
    location <- paste(getwd(), directory, sep="/")
    filenames <- list.files(location, full.names = TRUE)
    dat <- data.frame()
    for(i in id) {
        data <- read.csv(filenames[i])
        data <- na.omit(data)
        df <- data.frame("id" = i, "nobs" = nrow(data))
        dat <- rbind(dat, df)
    }
    dat
}
```

But when I input the following code from the quiz:

```
set.seed(42) 
cc <- complete("specdata", 332:1) 
use <- sample(332, 10) 
print(cc[use, "nobs"])
```

My output "87 96 576 76 237 4 121 117 361 932", is even not any of the options in the quiz. The correct output should be "711 135 74 445 178 73 49 0 687 237".

I've tried following demo data and they all work. The outputs are the same as the demo results.

```
complete("specdata", 1) 
##   id nobs
## 1  1  117

complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12)) 
##   id nobs
## 1  2 1041
## 2  4  474
## 3  8  192
## 4 10  148
## 5 12   96

complete("specdata", 30:25) 
##   id nobs
## 1 30  932
## 2 29  711
## 3 28  475
## 4 27  338
## 5 26  586
## 6 25  463

complete("specdata", 3)
##   id nobs
## 1  3  243
```

So I couldn't figure it out. Look forward to your insights. Thank you.

Due to the R version, the sample is changed. I use R3.6.0 while the quiz answers are generated in the older version. Here is the solution suggestion from Coursera study forum:

```
> vstr <- "3.5.1"  ## This choice works, you do not 
## need to have this version of R on your computer

> RNGversion(vstr)  ## do this once in your R session

## before taking any quiz questions using the sample function
## This "tells" R to run the random number generators
## from that version of R
## It returns a warning saying that version of sample is
## not "best"
Warning message:
In RNGkind("Mersenne-Twister", "Inversion", "Rounding") :
  non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
```

Then run the script and input the code from quiz.

Now it works! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried but the output is still "87 96 576 76 237 4 121 117 361 932", not the quiz answer.

Comment: Your post is not reproducible i.e. we don't have your data or quiz about what is going on behind the hood

Comment: I learn from the coursera study forum that due to the changes in R 3.6.0, "the default method for generating from a discrete uniform distribution (used in sample(), for instance) has been changed." I am using R3.6.0 while the quiz answers are in the older version of R. Here are the steps I have just done and now it works! input < vstr <- "3.5.1" <RNGversion(vstr)  then run the script and input the quiz code.

Comment: Yes, `sample` is now changed in behavior.